# Need help understanding how to add and/remove objects within nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, rails-activerecord

I am having trouble adding the data from a nested model to my database.

I have a Photo model with the following relationship to a Monster model. I am able to add and remove my nested form for monsters, but can't figure out how to actually add a new Monster object when updating my Photo. This is based on 1 nested level form from the http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised example, basically the Survey - Question relationship demonstrated.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :monsters_attributes

  has_and_belongs_to_many :monsters

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :monsters, allow_destroy: true
end

class Monster < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :selected

  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
end
```

I'm sure the trouble is in my photos_controller and my poor understanding of how to use the params submitted when I update my photo form. I get the following params hash when submitting an edit photo form with two monsters. The first one is already associated and the second one I am trying to declare by clicking an "Add Monster" link, entering the first and last name, and submitting the form.

The "Add Monster" link is defined in my _form.html.erb file for a Photo and I am using a partial to render the fields. The helper function is declared in application_helper.rb.

#### _form.html.erb

```
…
    <!-- this uses the _monster_fields partial -->
    <%= f.fields_for :monsters do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'monster_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>        

  </table>

  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Monster", f, :monsters %>
...

application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new  # make instance of monster association record, Monster.new
    id = new_object.object_id                          # get id of new monster object, id = Monster.new.object_id

    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)    # render partial _monster_fields.html.erb
    end

    link_to(name, "#", class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", '&#xA')}) # returns a link    
  end
end
```

#### params shown from edit (update) of photo to show:

```
{
"utf8"=>"✓", 
"_method"=>"put", 
"authenticity_token"=>"8dYkFrzdkulBv8YrZCHU2wfFh4v5LQc9q/JWPmsbDkc=", 
"photo"=>{"title"=>"Family Gathering", 
    "monsters_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{"first_name"=>"Franken", "last_name"=>"Stein", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"1"}, 
    "1358291763102"=>{"first_name"=>"Ware", "last_name"=>"Wolf", "_destroy"=>"false"}
    }, 
    "monster_ids"=>"1"
   }, 
"commit"=>"Update Photo", 
"action"=>"update", 
"controller"=>"photos", 
"id"=>"1"
}
```

In my applcation.js file I define how to handle the adding and removal of fields. In .add_fields, the example uses the id for my newly created object but I don't see how to save my newly created monster in the monsters table.

#### application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').on('click', '.remove_fields', function(event) {
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1');
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
    time = new Date().getTime();
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))    
    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Overall, it's a pretty simple process but I'm not sure how to proceed further when it comes to actually saving a new Monster from my Photo edit view(creating a new active record object).

Could I have issues using a many-to-many relationship?

The example from railscasts is good but it doesn't quite go that far. I am grateful for any assistance someone may have.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

### updated 1/16/13: My params hash and the error I get

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PhotosController#update

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: monster_ids

app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:76:in `block in update'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:75:in`update'

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1l62Sged52hnEHQoj0WPf/asRjcIpIKBBzsb7gVDRm0=",
 "photo"=>{"title"=>"Family Gathering",
 "monsters_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"Franken",
 "last_name"=>"Stein",
 "_destroy"=>"false",
 "id"=>"1"},
 "1358356969634"=>{"first_name"=>"Scary",
 "last_name"=>"Frank",
 "_destroy"=>"false"}},
 "monster_ids"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Update Photo",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of the nested attributes stuff is that the implications for your controller code are non existent. You can keep doing

```
photo.update_attributes params[:photo]
```

and monsters will get updated and deleted as appropriate: `photo.monsters_attributes=` will be called by update_attributes with the data from `params[:photo][:monsters_attributes]`. Calling `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will have (among other things) created a suitable `monsters_attributes=` method

Comment: Thank's for this. I think I almost have it working. I currently get an error when trying to update my photo with new monsters. 

Error: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in     PhotosController#update
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: monster_ids
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:76:in `block in update'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:75:in `update'

Comment: You do need to make   monsters_attributes acessible. I'm not sure where the monsters_ids parameter comes from - it shouldn't be needed

Comment: I have attr_accessible :title, :monsters_attributes in my Photo model. Does it need to be anywhere else? Maybe the monsters_ids comes form using has_and_belongs_to_many :monsters?

Comment: I don't recall seeing association_name_ids in this context. Where are the (presumably hidden) form inputs named photo[monster_ids] ?

Comment: Ok I found the error for this. I had a stray dropdown box with all my monsters listed so when I submitted the form this was included in the params. oops! I am able to add new monsters to the photo, they appear in the monsters table, however when I use my remove links when editing a photo, the added monsters still exist in my monsters table. Shouldn't adding or removing handle this in the table as well?

Comment: In my Photo model I have the line below and can see that "_destroy" is present in params as "false" or "1" if I clicked on my remove link during a Photo edit.
accepts_nested_attributes_for :monsters, allow_destroy: true